# ContentOffset and back to Top issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView with paging. I declare it:

```
   if(_fullPosterScroll == nil) _fullPosterScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:rc];
    [_fullPosterScroll setDelegate:self];
    [_fullPosterScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [_fullPosterScroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    _fullPosterScroll.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    _fullPosterScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;
    _fullPosterScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _fullPosterScroll.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
    _fullPosterScroll.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

And after a tap i call a method:

```
[_fullPosterScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_selectedPosterPosition*(_fullPosterScroll.frame.size.width), 0) animated:YES];
NSLog(@"%f",_fullPosterScroll.contentOffset.y);
```

Why after that in Log i have for example 225.00 ?! This should be 0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, but you should check to make sure that `setContentOffset` isn't triggering any delegate methods that are changing offset.

Also, Apple have a sample project, [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html), that does exactly what you want, so you should look at that if you want a complete example.